# How to Edit Or Modify a Stored Procedure?

Tags: plsql

I have created a Stored Procedure with the name getRecords 1 month ago,

I want to edit that Stored procedure getRecords ,

Please tell me how to modify the Stored procedure

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`. See [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php), for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CREATE OR REPLACE` instead of simply using `CREATE`

To display old procedure see the `USER_SOURCE` table.

Answer (score 0):

go to the sp and right click - modify

then change the

```
**create getRecords  -> alter getRecords**
```

Answer (score 0):

what database system?

if mssql then the syntax for it is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762.aspx

So you would do something like

ALTER PROCEDURE schemaname.procedurename ...

Comment: The "plsql" tag strongly indicates that it's an Oracle database, although it *could* be DB2 or perhaps others.